# Multiplication with html, json and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I am trying to get data from mysql and use it to calculate energy, proteins, carbs and fat.

**Formula:**

```
The formula for energy: (energy*inp_size_a_1)/100;
The formula for proteins: (proteins*inp_size_a_1)/100;
The formula for carbs: (carbs*inp_size_a_1)/100;
The formula for fat: (fat*inp_size_a_1)/100;
```

**From search.php I get json data:**

```
[{
    "food_name": "Frosne ekstra grove rundstykker",
    "energy": "250",
    "proteins": "18",
    "carbohydrates": "25",
    "fat": "6"
}, {
    "food_name": "Frosen brokkoliblanding",
    "energy": "26",
    "proteins": "2",
    "carbohydrates": "4",
    "fat": "0"
}, {
    "food_name": "Frossen kyllingfilet",
    "energy": "94",
    "proteins": "21",
    "carbohydrates": "1",
    "fat": "0"
}]
```

**This is my HTML:**

```
<!-- Food Autocomplete -->
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#inp_meal_a_1" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'search.php'
    });
});
</script>
<!-- //Food Autocomplete -->



<input type="text" name="inp_size_a_1" value="" size="3" tabindex="6" id="inp_size_a_1" />
<input type="text" name="inp_meal_a_1" value="" size="40" tabindex="8" id="inp_meal_a_1" />
<input type="text" name="inp_energy_a_1" value="" size="10" id="inp_energy_a_1" />
<input type="text" name="inp_proteins_a_1" value="" size="10" id="inp_proteins_a_1" />
<input type="text" name="inp_carbs_a_1" value="" size="10" id="inp_carbs_a_1" />
<input type="text" name="inp_fat_a_1" value="" size="10" id="inp_fat_a_1" />
```

What should I do to complete this?

Comment: What would be your `inp_size_a_1`?

Comment: Well I suggest R.T.M or find a javascripy and jQuery tutorial there are hundereds out there. Otherwise this looks more like a specification than a question and we dont work from specifications as **SO is not a free code resourse**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your json to look like this:

```
[{
    "value": "Frosne ekstra grove rundstykker",
    "energy": "250",
    "proteins": "18",
    "carbohydrates": "25",
    "fat": "6"
}, {
    "value": "Frosen brokkoliblanding",
    "energy": "26",
    "proteins": "2",
    "carbohydrates": "4",
    "fat": "0"
}, {
    "value": "Frossen kyllingfilet",
    "energy": "94",
    "proteins": "21",
    "carbohydrates": "1",
    "fat": "0"
}]
```

Whatever value you need in autocomplete should be in "value" in your json.
Your code should be:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
            $( "#inp_meal_a_1" ).autocomplete({
                source: 'search.php'
            });
            $('#inp_meal_a_1').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
                var val = $('#inp_size_a_1').val();
                var energy = ui.item.energy;
                var proteins = ui.item.proteins;
                var carbohydrates = ui.item.carbohydrates;
                var fat = ui.item.fat;
                $("#inp_energy_a_1").val((energy*val)/100);
                $("#inp_proteins_a_1").val((proteins*val)/100);
                $("#inp_carbs_a_1").val((carbohydrates*val)/100);
                $("#inp_fat_a_1").val((fat*val)/100);
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Great code! I need to make adjustment to the autocomplete, but the rest is nice!

Answer (score 0):

Give the `change` event with it. Almost you are there:

```
$( "#inp_meal_a_1" ).autocomplete({
  source: 'search.php'
}).change(function () {
  // Set your values here.
  $("#inp_meal_a_1").val();
  $("#inp_energy_a_1").val();
  $("#inp_proteins_a_1").val();
  $("#inp_carbs_a_1").val();
  $("#inp_fat_a_1").val();
});
```